# Use mmap to allocate memory

Tags: c, posix, mmap

I need to allocate memory but I can't use `malloc` because its not reentrant, so basically I will implement dynamic memory allocation using POSIX `mmap` function. Is it possible to use `mmap`?

Comment: "reentrant" is usually understood to include all leaf functions such as `malloc`. `malloc` does not have a callback mechanism to your code, so there's no way you could re-enter it anyway (on the same thread). Any reentrancy would be wholly within and under the control of the standard libray itself.

Comment: @MSalters: Presumably he wants to allocate memory in a signal handler, in which case malloc() not being reentrant is a problem.

Comment: @janneb: Isn't that disallowed anyway?

Comment: @MSalters: Ah, you're right; mmap() is not async-signal-safe. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Yes, mmap() should be reentrant so you should be able to use that. Note that mmap() is often a quite slow operation so you're probably better of using it only in those (hopefully) few and far between cases where it's really needed, rather than as a general purpose malloc() replacement.</strike>

[POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) contains a list of async-signal-safe functions that are safe to call from a signal handler function (see the table in section 2.4.2 in the link). mmap() is not in that list, that is, calling mmap() from a signal handling function may result in undefined behavior.

What you can do is to avoid allocating memory in signal handlers, just set some flag and do the actual work later.

Comment: It doesn't work always, for example if the task of the signal handler is exactly to save the signal data (for later processing). malloc() can't be used because of reentrancy, the stack can't be used because it will be destroyed on the handler return, this is how the OP started to think on some uncommon workaround.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: replaced reentrant by thread-safe

malloc is thread-safe on most OS.

Which one are you using and are you sure it is not thread-safe?
Or do you need it to be reentrant (I guess not)?

Comment: I'm using in glibc, so I guess its a non-reentrant function. Do you think I can use malloc?

Comment: On most systems today malloc is thread-safe but not reentrant.

Comment: Yes you can use glibc malloc. As janneb says, it is thread-safe and not reentrant, but I guess that's what you need.

Comment: @sasayins Why do you need a reentrant malloc ? If you simply need to allocate memory in several threads, you're fine. malloc is thread safe. If you need to allocate memory in a signal handler, you CANNOT do that. If you need something else, please explain.

Comment: @nos It could be needed on many reasons, for example signal handlers, but some low-level interrupt handling is also possible, although it is mainly a kernel thing. This question asks for the feasibility of a workaround to avoid this obstacle on a lower level.